# Zbarcam-Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, webcam, qr-code, zbar

I am trying to get my webcam (connected to a Pi) to read qr codes. I was using zbar-tools for this but am currently getting the following error:

```
ERROR: zbar processor in zbar_processor_init():
system error : spawning input thread : invalid argument (22)
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This one worked on Arch

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so zbarcam --raw /dev/video0

from:
https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/installing-and-using-zbar-in-linux-to-scan-bar-codes-with-your-webcam/

Comment: Please, try to describe

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error message from within python when I was using python-zbar. I knew I needed something like the --nodisplay flag, however this is only available at the zbarcam command line. My solution was to look into the python-zbar sources where I found a second undocumented argument for proc.int():

```
import zbar
proc = zbar.Processor()
device = '/dev/video0'
proc.init(device,False)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, while connecting remotely, adding the flag `--nodisplay` helped me:
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ zbarcam /dev/video0 --nodisplay`

(the device might be different for you, try `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/video?` for discovering what your connected devices are)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. The issue was that I was connecting via SSH. I would recommend that you first start the Raspberry Pi GUI using `startx`, then run your command from the Terminal editor. You can also opt to disable the display using the `zbarcam --nodisplay` flag.

If that still doesn't work, as it didn't for me, I started receiving a new error message:

```
unsupported request: no compatible image format
```

I discovered, from [this](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/installing-and-using-zbar-in-linux-to-scan-bar-codes-with-your-webcam/) article, that you can use a prefix to launch zbar, which I had to slightly modify to:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libv4l/v4l1compat.so zbarcam --raw /dev/video0
```

This is the command that finally worked for me.